# asp.net core 2.1 app not sending httponly cookies in Http response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm adding support for authentication cookies for my .net core 2.1 webapp. I inject cookies in after successful login like this:

```
 Response.Cookies.Append("session", "dummySessionIdToBeReplaced", new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None
        });
```

This works fine while testing locally (dotnet run), i.e. I can see "Set-Cookie: ..." header in the http response for login.
But "Set-Cookie" header is missing totally when I run the app in AWS (under ECS service). Dockerfile content here:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/publish .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Staging
EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "backend.dll"]
```

The only thing that really differs in local vs. AWS is that while running locally both frontend and backend are served from localhost.

Comment: Just to test - what happens if you set `HttepOnly` to `false`?

Comment: `HttpOnly` affects the client. It simply tells it to not expose the cookies via JavaScript. That is all. It has no bearing on whether or not the cookie is set in the first place. There's something else going on, but there's not enough code provided to determine what.

Comment: I tested this now with both httponly and 'standard' cookie. And also tested with two browsers - Ms Edge and Chrome. Surprisingly with MS Edge Set-Cookie header is present (both httponly and standard cookies) but with Chrome both are missing.

Comment: I did more testing and realized that the cookie is indeed passed to browser (both edge and chrome) and also passed on to further calls to backend. But chrome just seems to hide the cookies, cannot figure out why.